# How to make VS Code's auto-complete more strict?

Tags: configuration, visual-studio-code

I love Visual Studio Code, but its Intellisense auto-complete drives me crazy and I make more typos with it than it helps.  So I feel I must be using it wrong.

The problem is very hard to explain, so I have a screenshot below:

[image: VS Code auto-complete]

I typed in `thi`.  I would hope/expect/want that autocomplete would **only** look for anything to autocomplete that contains `thi` in consecutive order.  But it does not. Instead it looks for *anything* with the letters `t`, `h`, and `i` in them.  They needn't be next to each other, nor does the thing of interest even need to start with `t`.

---

I would like to "tame" auto-complete to only find consecutive letters.  Is there a way to do this?  (I use Python, Javascript, and SQL for most of my work, but I'm hoping the config is cross-language.)

Ideally, I would like the auto-complete to (a) **require all letters be consecutive**, (b) **not** require the thing of interest to start with those letters, and (c) ignore upper/lower case.  But by far the most important issue to me is resolving (a).

Comment: That sounds like a very interesting request but a hard one to configure because it may be part of the actual configuration of VS Code.  Considering VS Code is Open Source maybe you can play with that there.  The only other possible option I could think of is VS Code Typings.  This won't "tame" you intellisense, it will just make your suggestions more specific.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know about VS Code Typings.  I'll have to check it out.  I'm surprised this is hard; I cannot be the only one who feels like VS Code is giving out **way too many** suggestions.

Comment: You probably aren't the only one who thinks this.  I like to have options but un-wanted, invalid, or un-needed suggestions definitely should be excluded.  You don't want to see Angular directive options if you haven't included them and/or in a different file type.  However, I wouldn't be surprised that this type checking isn't included on purpose to help speed up the file.

Comment: There is nothing to directly disable fuzzy matching as of now and it is quite useful in some cases as well. But you can try exploring `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "none",
    "editor.suggestSelection": "recentlyUsedByPrefix"` and see if it helps with the order you want to see?

Comment: updated answer including info from @TarunLalwani, GitHub, and VS Code docs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you are having is a feature added in [November 2017 update](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_19#_smarter-intellisense). There is currently no way to turn off fuzzy autocomplete, but the issue is currently open on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/52789) and the setting to change this behavior will be added.

In the meantime you can tweak your autocomplete with these settings:

```
"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,
"javascript.nameSuggestions": false,
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "bottom", // inline, none
"editor.suggestSelection": "recentlyUsedByPrefix"
```

From [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_suggestion-selection):

> When using the last option, `recentlyUsedByPrefix`, VS Code remembers which item was selected for a specific prefix (partial text). For example, if you typed co and then selected console, the next time you typed `co`, the suggestion `console` would be pre-selected.
> This lets you quickly map various prefixes to different suggestions,
> for example:
> `co -> console` and `con -> const`.

And maybe:

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": false,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": false
  },
```

It doesn't solve your problem completely, but it's the closest you can get without digging through VS Code source and creating an extension.

Comment: This is great, @Braca!  It seems to be a bit more aggressive than I'd like, such that very little is auto-completing, but that's far better than the insane fuzzy complete.  And I appreciate the link to the GitHub issue for this fix!  ;-p  200 reputation points well spent!

Comment: Thanks @MikeWilliamson, the good news is that there will be a setting for this behavior

Comment: Did anyone test that toggle mentioned in the issue? Seems to affect nothing at all here.

Comment: Any news on this? It is almost 2021 and it seems that we cannot disable fuzzy completion.

Comment: @RaulDurand I do not know of any news or updates, but I *did* use Braca's solution (tweaking my autocomplete suggestions), and it "fixed" the problem by essentially removing autocomplete almost entirely.  But this is actually not a bad solution, because lots of plugins have their own shortcuts to generate boilerplate, etc.